# Cut string within a specific pattern in python

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics

I have string of some length consisting of only 4 characters which are 'A,T,G and C'. I have pattern 'GAATTC' present multiple times in the given string. I have to cut the string at intervals where this pattern is..
For example for a string, 'ATC**GAATTC**ATA', I should get output of

- string one - `ATCGA`
- string two - `ATTCATA`

I am newbie in using Python but I have come up with the following (incomplete) code:

```
seq = seq.upper()
str1 = "GAATTC"
seqlen = len(seq)
seq = list(seq)

for i in range(0,seqlen-1):
    site = seq.find(str1)
    print(site[0:(i+2)])
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why does the expected output contain parts of the splitter string and how are we supposed to divide it into string one and string two?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 How do I cut the string? I want to find the pattern 'GAATTC' and within that pattern I want to split the string at 'GA', such that the resulting string will give me the fast half of upto GA and the second half from ATTC onwards. This is in relation to the  example mentioned above. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel; BioPython has some features specially to deal with restriction enzyme sites http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/Restriction.html

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks, for the advice. I am fully aware of BioPython. However, my aim is to perform this exercise without using BioPython modules. Nonetheless, thanks again!

Comment: @Srk Well if this is just a practice exercise then fine, but if you actually plan to *use* your code then I recommend using BioPython

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First lets develop your idea of using find, so you can figure out your mistakes.

```
seq = 'ATCGAATTCATAATCGAATTCATAATCGAATTCATA'
seq = seq.upper()
pattern = "GAATTC"
split_at = 2
seqlen = len(seq)
i = 0

while i < seqlen:
    site = seq.find(pattern, i)
    if site != -1:
       print(seq[i: site + split_at])
       i = site + split_at
    else:
       print seq[i:]
       break
```

Yet python string sports a powerful replace method that directly replaces fragments of string. The below snippet uses the replace method to insert separators when needed:

```
seq = 'ATCGAATTCATAATCGAATTCATAATCGAATTCATA'
seq = seq.upper()
pattern = "GA","ATTC"
pattern1 = ''.join(pattern) # 'GAATTC'
pattern2 = ' '.join(pattern) # 'GA ATTC'
splited_seq = seq.replace(pattern1, pattern2) # 'ATCGA ATTCATAATCGA ATTCATAATCGA ATTCATA'
print (splited_seq.split())
```

I believe it is more intuitive and should be faster then RE (which might have lower performance, depending on library and usage)

Comment: The Second solution is pretty amazing as to first. Having said that even the first solution works and is great as well. Thank you to you Big Time!

Comment: @Srk Thanks, I enjoyed too, yet was a bit surprised how I did not realize the second solution immediately. Added benefit, replace would work with any text editor. Btw if you find solution useful, do not hesitate to up-vote or accept.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution :

```
seq = 'ATCGAATTCATA'
seq_split = seq.upper().split('GAATTC')
result = [ 
    (seq_split[i]  + 'GA') if i % 2 == 0 else ('ATTC' + seq_split[i]) 
    for i in range(len(seq_split)) if len(seq_split[i]) > 0 
]
```

Result :

```
print(result)
['ATCGA', 'ATTCATA']
```

Comment: This won't work if 'GAATTC' is present multiple times in the given string

Comment: @ Thanks! Your suggestion does work. However, it is limited to only one occurrence of the pattern. If the pattern 'GAATTC' occurs multiple times the next occurrence is not considered.

Comment: Updated for multiple occurrences .

Answer (score 1):

BioPython has a restriction enzyme package to do exactly what you're asking.

```
from Bio.Restriction import *
from Bio.Alphabet.IUPAC import IUPACAmbiguousDNA

print(EcoRI.site) # You will see that this is the enzyme you listed above

test = 'ATCGAATTCATA'.upper() # This is the sequence you want to search
my_seq = Seq(test, IUPACAmbiguousDNA()) # Create a biopython Seq object with our sequence

cut_sites = EcoRI.search(my_seq)
```

`cut_sites` contain a list of exactly where to cut the input sequence (such that `GA` is in the left sequence and `ATTC` is in the right sequence.

You can then split the sequence into contigs using:

```
cut_sites = [0] + cut_sites # We add a leading zero so this works for the first
                            # contig. This might not always be needed.
contigs = [test[i:j] for i,j in zip(cut_sites, cut_sites[1:]+[None])]
```

You can [see this page](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/Restriction.html#1) for more details about BioPython.

Comment: I was having a pretty hard time accessing the module, in anyways thank you for the solution and it worked perfectly well for me!

Answer (score 0):

My code is a bit sloppy, but you could try something like this when you want to iterate over multiple occurrences of the string

```
def split_strings(seq):
    string1 = seq[:seq.find(str1) +2]
    string2 = seq[seq.find(str1) +2:]
    return string1, string2


test = 'ATCGAATTCATA'.upper()
str1 = 'GAATTC'

seq = test
while str1 in seq:
    string1, seq = split_strings(seq)
    print string1
print seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the regular expression module:

```
import re
seq = 'ATCGAATTCATA'
restriction_site = re.compile('GAATTC')
subseq_start = 0
for match in restriction_site.finditer(seq):
   print seq[subseq_start:match.start()+2]
   subseq_start = match.start()+2
print seq[subseq_start:]
```

Output:

```
ATCGA
ATTCATA
```